# get problems when C# invoke powershell scripts

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core-2.1

I created a console application (base on .net core 2.1) for C# invoking Powershell script, but I got NULL value.  Could someone tell me where/which/What step is wrong or missing?

Below is the exception details:

[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2fpl.png)

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {    //.net core 2.1
        string ScriptsText = @"C:\temp\getEvent.ps1";

        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        runspace.Open();

        PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();
        shell.AddScript(ScriptsText);
        shell.Runspace = runspace;

        Collection<PSObject> psObjects = shell.Invoke();
        //format the psobjects to string object
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in psObjects)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }
        runspace.Close();
        Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Variable:psobjects should contains the result after the invoke, but now show null value

Attached the powershell script content:
C:\temp\getEvent.ps1:

$result= Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 5;
return $result

**prepared different powershell scripts for testing purpose**

1. part cmdlet can work properly (see below screenshot)
2. part cmdlet returns null when invoked by C# (see below screenshot)

[Same C# code invoke powershell script, return null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Icqd0.png)

[Same C# code invoke powershell script, return null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4yXL.png)

[Same C# code invoke powershell script, return value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kpwg.png)

[Same C# code invoke powershell script, return value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi3VR.png)

Comment: Attached the powershell script content:
C:\temp\getEvent.ps1:

$result= Get-EventLog -LogName System -Newest 5 | out-string
return $result

Comment: Is `psObjects` null or one of the contained `obj`?

Comment: `PowerShell.AddScript` doesn't seem to accept a file name, try reading the file content as a string and passing the string to `PowerShell.AddScript`.

Comment: @KlausGütter: psobjects variable show null.

Comment: @KlausGütter
psObjects shows null.

Comment: @Klaus,  For powershell.addscript("d:\path\to\ps.ps1 parameter1value  parametervalue2") , i tested it, it can work .